# Is it possible to restart the network card of a Windows desktop remotely?

Tags: remote-desktop

In my company, we have a wfh polciy for which we connect to our desktop in the office remotely from home.

But when we lock our machines and go away for sometime, the network connection in our desktops go down (but the machine stays ON though)

So we are unable to connect to our deskops from home. As a fix for this, someone from the office just needs to login to our machines. After they login, the network comes up in a few seconds and then we can login from home.

As a solution to this problem, I was thinking is it possible for support team to restarr the network card remotely? Am expecting this would bring the network up (the machine would remain locked and powered ON. And the network also will be up) so that we can login remotely without any help from someone in the team (the desktop support team should be available to help though but they can also restart our network card from their hom am sure).

Please advise. Am I thinking on the right lines here? Or is ther another solution to this?

Comment: And how should they to that when the network card is down? Find out why it "goes down" and fix it. Most probably it's just a setting in the driver.

Comment: Never seen that - looks m,ore like a driver issue and possibly crappy hardware? I would fix the core problem.

Comment: I would recommend to check power saving options for NICs. It looks like, they are deactivated because of inactivity.

Comment: @batistuta09 - Could you please point me to how I can check this settings? I am new to this. Thanks!

Comment: @Biju , check this guide - https://help.theatremanager.com/installing-theatre-manager/disable-power-saving-ethernet